# I'm looking to identify this IC. Number is CS2918EB

Tags: relay, integrated-circuit, identification

[image]

Markings: CS2918EB
SZTA1T8005L

It's 16-pin and is on a microwave oven control board and it's connected to relays and a control chip.

Comment: You have, with those numbers. If you want us to suggest where and how to buy then that is likely off-topic.

Comment: Can’t find it. Don’t recognize the logo but “CS” and microwave oven hints to Chip Star. Perhaps a customized version of one of their standard offerings?

Comment: Manufacturers are increasingly using custom parts.  IC's, transformers, power modules, even custom electrolytic caps.  Some people are not tolerating it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_to_repair

Comment: Trace the circuit. Which pins are the power pins, and what voltages do they go to? What does each other pin connect to?

Comment: @rdtsc And a whole lot of people refuse to pay what electronics should realistically get priced as. It's ridiculous that a wood board costs more than a 32 bit MCU and a wooden desk costs more than the PC sitting on it. In order to maintain these completely unrealistic price expectations, taking shortcuts in electronics design is just the beginning of it - designers of commercial electronics are literally forced to review their products to ensure that there's not a single high quality item present. How about starting the "right to pay what it should actually cost" movement. No, not interested?